# ¿Cómo copiar el contenido de un fichero a partir de una determinada línea en Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo un fichero que deseo copiar en otro a partir de una determinada línea.

¿Es posible hacerlo con un solo comando, sin tener que hacerlo con un bucle con `cat` e ir copiandolo línea a línea?

Es decir, algo como lo siguiente si quisiera copiar desde la quinta línea:

```
cat fichero_completo.txt | wc - l -5 > fichero_recortado.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Con el comando `tail` puedes hacerlo, usando la bandera `-n` y como argumento `+5`.

El resultado lo diriges a un fichero y listo:

```
$ tail -n+5 fichero_completo.txt > fichero_recortado.txt
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat hita.txt                                                                                                       
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0

$ tail -n+5 hita.txt                                                                                                 
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como comenta toledano en su correcta respuesta, `tail` parece ser la solución más óptima:

```
tail -n +LINEA_A_PARTIR_DE_LA_CUAL_IMPRIMIR
```

De `man tail`:

> **-n, --lines=[+]NUM**
>   extrae las últimas NUM líneas, en lugar de las últimas 10; o usa `-n +NUM` para extraer a partir de la línea NUM.

De todos modos, hay a veces controversia en el uso de tail (que si `tail -NUM`, que si `tail -n +NUM`, etc), por lo que yo tiendo a usar `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>=LINEA_A_PARTIR_DE_LA_CUAL_IMPRIMIR' fichero
```

Que usa la variable `NR` donde se guarda el número de registro, es decir, el número de línea. Esto te permite también hacer lo mismo para muchos ficheros de golpe:

```
awk 'FNR>=LINEA_A_PARTIR_DE_LA_CUAL_IMPRIMIR' ficheros*
```

Donde `FNR` indica número de registro de cada fichero.

Finalmente, con `sed` puedes eliminar todas las líneas anteriores:

```
sed '1,ÚLTIMO_LINEA_A_SALTAR d'
```

Que es lo mismo que pedirle que solo imprima a partir de una dada:

```
sed -n 'LINEA_A_PARTIR_DE_LA_CUAL_IMPRIMIR,$ p'
```

---

Probemos las soluciones anteriores con `seq`, que imprime muchos números de golpe:

```
$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Ve cómo se imprimen todas las líneas a partir de la 7.ª:

```
$ seq 10 | tail -n +7
7
8
9
10
```

Con `awk`:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR>=7'
7
8
9
10
```

Con `sed`:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '1,6d'
7
8
9
10

$ seq 10 | sed -n '7,$ p'
7
8
9
10
```